# How to open a folder in Visual Studio Code using AppleScript?

Tags: macos, finder, applescript, visual-studio-code

I'm looking to create an AppleScript which helps me open VSCode in a specific folder (in order to be able to use it in the toolbar in Finder). I've written the following code:

```
tell application "Finder"
    if exists Finder window 1 then
        set currentFolder to target of Finder window 1 as alias
    else
        return
    end if
end tell
tell application "Visual Studio Code" to open quoted form of POSIX path of currentFolder
```

However, this isn't working. I've never used AppleScript before, so I'm unaware of what I'm doing wrong.

How could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost got it, just one small bug:

> ```
> tell application "Visual Studio Code" to open quoted form of POSIX path of currentFolder
> ```

`open` is part of the Standard Suite and opens files and folders directly.

```
tell application "Visual Studio Code" to open currentFolder
```